# Set the regular expression in Monaco Editor through the SetValue() method

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

```
 require.config({ paths: { 'vs': './min/vs' }});
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
    var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        
        language: 'text/javascript'
    });
    
    editor.setValue("new RegExp('/\d{3}/')");

    console.log(editor.getValue());
});
```

result is  new RegExp('/d{3}/')

The displayed result is missing the "" in the regular, \d becomes d

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backwards slash with another backwards slash -> \\

```js
editor.setValue("new RegExp('/\\d{3}/')");
```

This is a string at this point, the regex escape has no effect. A backwards slash in javascript starts an [escape sequence](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes).